# yii2 отдельный шаблон с видами для мобильных устройств

Tags: php, yii2

Как в Yii для мобильных устройств с либой mobile detect подгружать отдельный шаблон с видами?

Comment: Уже давно пора переходить на апи. Тогда проще будет с клиентами. А если надо в браузере, то адаптивная верстка нужна.

Comment: Для верстки - `bootstrap` Вам в помощь - https://getbootstrap.com/
Если же именно подгрузить определенный шаблон в зависимости от того, с мобилы клиент или нет - после того как удостоверились, что клиент с мобильного телефона - указываете шаблон из папки `views/layouts` внутри контроллера `$this->layout = 'my_layout';`